# The Property 'Command' was not found in type 'InvokeCommandAction' for combobox

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, mvvm

I have a combobox in silverlight mvvm. i need to wrote the event for combobox name 'SelectionChanged'. i Create the coding below but it gives an error.. "The Property 'Command' was not found in type 'InvokeCommandAction' "

Note: I am not using Silverlight Light. I'm using Silverlight5 and its a silverlight application.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="myComboBox" Width="150" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" >
                                    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <StackPanel>
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                                            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LoadCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=myComboBox}" />
                                        </i:EventTrigger>
                                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                </ComboBox>
```

this line the error comes.

```
<i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LoadCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=myComboBox}" />
```

Comment: Which version of Silverlight are you using?  Is this a Silverlight app or a WP7 app?

Comment: I'm using Silverlight 5.. its Silverlight app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Finally i found the solution for it..
i include the below in the XAML page:

```
 xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
             xmlns:si="clr-namespace:Expression.Samples.Interactivity;assembly=Expression.Samples.Interactivity"
```

then the code for combobox is:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Employees,Mode=TwoWay}"  DisplayMemberPath="Dept" SelectedItem="{Binding Names, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="130,117,0,0" Height="26" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="120">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                    <si:CallDataMethod Method="AddEmployee"/>
                    <si:SetProperty TargetName="LayoutRoot" PropertyName="Background" Value="PaleGoldenrod"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </ComboBox>
```

Here Employees is like a datasource to get all the employee in Observable Collections.
that code be written in Employee.cs file.

then we access the ComboboxSelected event as follow..
Goto ViewModel Folder and Wrote the function named as follows,

```
public void AddEmployee()
{
//Your Code....
}
```

Happy Coding...!

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be working for me. Make sure that you:

1. Install Blend Preview for SL5 from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9503)
2. Reference `System.Windows.Interactivity` and `Microsoft.Expression.Interactions` in your Silverlight project
3. Define the correct namespace in XAML: `xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"`

Comment: note that this answer applied to me (just step 2 - adding the reference) even if I dont use SilverLight (wpf 4.5)